# Any user can't sign in with Azure SSO after using AJAX forms. Probably AJAX forms are making something wrong to App Pool (Asp.Net 4.7.2 MVC))

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-ajax, azure-ad-b2c, application-pool

Every time I use an AJAX form, everything works correctly, but if a user later wants to log in through Azure SSO, he does not leave it and loops. You would think these AJAX forms are causing something in the App Pool. Because then I have to wait an indefinite time so that any user can log in or restart the App Pool

Comment: Can you explain more what this means “ he does not leave it and loops”, Leave what? What loops? What AJAX code did you add? Where is this AJAX code?

Comment: As @JasSuri mentioned, please consider posting the relevant code and errors you encounter.